# Width of jQuery UI datepicker when using numberOfMonths: [2, 6]

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I currently experimenting with the [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) widget from jQuery UI.
Im a using jQuery UI version 1.11.4

I have downloaded the sample file of jQuery UI which contains a short demo for all widgets in a index.html.
The html code for the datepicker is this:

```
   <!-- Datepicker -->
   <h2 class="demoHeaders">Datepicker</h2>
   <div id="datepicker"></div>
```

I would like to display 12 months in the date picker to use it as a calendar.
I tried out two configurations:

- Configuration A: 3 rows with 4 months
- Configuration B: 2 rows with 6 months

**Configuration A is working fine:**

```
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
         numberOfMonths: [3, 4],
     });
```

[image]

**But I' am having problems with configuration B**

```
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
       numberOfMonths: [2, 6],
   });
```

Here the width of the datepicker seems to be bigger than necessary, this causes the grey background to go too far to the right. I have put an '?' onto that area.

[image]

In Chrome dev tools, I can see the classes and css applied to it. It seems that the width in the style might be responsible, but this is generated by jQuery.

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-inline ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content 
ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-datepicker-multi-6 ui-datepicker-multi" 
style="width: 102em; display: block;">
```

DEMO:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display multiple months</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: [2,6],
      showButtonPanel: true
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Can somehow help me on how to display 2 rows with 6 months and not having the wrong width? Thank you.

**See in in jsfiddle:**

You can see here too: [jsfiddle.net/tvm6jrf5/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/tvm6jrf5/1/)

Comment: What version of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using? Can you recreate this is a stack snippet or jsFiddle?

Comment: I added the jqueryui version and created a link to a jsfiddle demo

Comment: But in your fiddle you're using jQuery 1.5.2 and UI 1.8.9

Comment: Oh ok. I copied / forked the fiddle from an existing one (in fact this was that very first fiddle I created). So the exact version dos note seem to matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out different possible solutions I found one that fits best for me, so I answer my own question here.

As I described above, the main problem is that JQuery UI applies a width using an inline style.

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-inline ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content 
ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-datepicker-multi-6 ui-datepicker-multi" 
style="width: 102em; display: block*;"
```

So there is no way to fix this using CSS, because the CSS would not be applied because of the inline style to the datepicker:

**Solution 1: Removing the style dynmically at runtime**

This was my first approach:

```
$("#calendar .ui-datepicker-inline").removeAttr("style");
```

I have a div with an id of "calendar" where the JQuery datepicker is placed in. So I used this JQuery command to remove the style attribute at runtime.

In addition I wrote some css to set the width myself:

```
#calendar .ui-datepicker-inline {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

At first this seemed to work, but some events causef the original wrong width to be re-applied (e.g. selecting a date, refreshing the widget, ...).
I realized that I would not want to remove the style dynamically again and again for each of those events.

**Solution 2: Changing the JQuery UI code which creates the style**

I finally decided to fix the code in JQuery UI which is causing this, i.e. the code which generates the style with the width.

It can be found in the _updateDatepicker function within the JQuery UI source file.

I changed the following:

Before:

```
inst.dpDiv.addClass("ui-datepicker-multi-" + cols).css("width", (width * cols) + "em");
```

After:

```
inst.dpDiv.addClass("ui-datepicker-multi-" + cols);
```

The idea to do this came from [this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-how-to-change-fixed-width-when-inline) thread in the JQuery forum where a user had the same problem.